What is the easiest way to update an LWC component on mobile user devices?
Whenever we have an update, currently we are pressing many buttons to clear the cache.
Examples are:

Clear Cache inside the SF app
Reload Salesforce button
Force stop in app info
Clear cache in app info

One way which seems to work is Restart Mobile Device.
Ideally we do not want the user to do anything, simply receive the updated code.
So far, 'Restart Mobile Device' seems to be the easiest solution. Any ideas?
